# How to use variable in calc function in css

Tags: html, css

How to store `-webkit-fill-available` in a variable and use it in a `calc` function in css **like this**:

```css
:root {
  --fullheight: -webkit-fill-available;
}

div {
  height: calc(var(--fullheight) - 50px);
}
```

I have tried this but it's not working for me

Comment: Why? `calc(-webkit-fill-available - 50px);` works?

Comment: Makes no sense to "store" `fill-available` of nothing into `:root`, right? Also, `fill-available` does not returns any value. You're basically trying to calc methods values with unit values...

Comment: I want a div of height of window(not 100vh) - 50px. How can I achieve that, `-webkit-fill-available` is used for the full window's height

Comment: But *window* *is* `v` (*viewport*).

Comment: Can you [edit] with a proper [mcve] of your issue please? Read [ask]. Otherwise this is an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: You cannot use predefined values inside calc()

Answer (score 0):

You should use `100dvh` instead. Here is a good explanation why, if you want to know the details.

https://www.bram.us/2021/07/08/the-large-small-and-dynamic-viewports/